# YAPMQ (Yet Another Python Modules Question

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Python 3.7, Ubuntu 20.10 (running on a VM).

I have the following directory structure:

```
application\
    __init__.py
    myfile.py
    modules\
        __init.py__
        mymodules.py
```

In myfile.py, I have the line

```
from application.modules import mymodules
```

which gives me the following:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'

Everything I have read on modules and packages says this should work, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you installed your module (i.e. added it to the python path)? If you haven't you can do this with a package manager (pip or poetry) and the appropriate package setup, or by calling `import sys; sys.path.append(<path-to-application>)`

Comment: How do you execute your code, i.e. from which working directory and which command do you use?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I'm running from the application directory with the command `python myfile.py`

Comment: From the application directory there is no module "application". From the parent directory there is. From the application directory, `from modules import ...` would work.

Comment: @Hoodlum - installing the module is problematic thanks to work's security policies. trying the `import sys` method gives me the same error

Comment: Installing modules is a matter of writing to your home directory. If that's a security problem, you have bigger problems (especially in a VM?!).

Comment: @mkrieger1 - my employers are pretty paranoid, yeah - in any case, your previous answer not only makes perfect sense, it also works!  Thank you!